# Importing M1 Forex data into MT4 History Center and generate M5, M15 and other higher order data

Tags: mt4

I have imported M1 data from 2000 to 2022 into MT4 and I thought the M5 to MN (monthly) data will be auto-computed based on the M1 data. But they remain empty.

How do I get the system to recompute them?

thanks